# Android AJAX Request using Json for Netflix failed - parsererror

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, json, device

**I have problem with a simple html page for mobile phones.**

Ajax request to the service odata.netflix.com works fine in every browser, including the iPhone, but not on the android browser.

Tested with three different versions of the androids, including ICS. Always the same message status is successful, but with parsererror.

I tried the Opera browser on all three Android devices, and it works without problems, but it does not work on Android browser.

I tried different versions of jQuery.

I tried getjson command.

I tried promisejs.js framework.

I tried various combinations of

```
cache: false;

crossDomain: true;

$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () { 
    $.support.cores = true; 
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true; 
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
});

$.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true; 
$.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
$.support.cores = true;
```

and none of it works on the **android browser**.

Any help is welcome.

Thanks in advance.